# Git Pull Deleted My Entire Project & Local Repository

Tags: git

I just finished a project I've been working on for a month and made a public github repository for it. I tried to push it but it told my to do a "git pull" so I did and now everything is gone! I tried git log but all it gives me is the commit from the remote repository.

[image]

I was using a local repository before this and it doesn't seem to be there anymore is there some sort of backup folder somewhere?

Comment: Look at the `reflog`.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH DANIEL! I was readying articles that just weren't helping! I don't know why I've already gotten two downvotes I really just couldn't find the right information

Comment: What version of Git are you running? `git pull` used to destroy repositories (sometimes irrecoverably, sometimes recoverable through the reflog) but since about Git 1.8 or so I haven't seen it do that. (I still don't *use* `git pull`, I use `git fetch` and then a second Git command, which is all `git pull` ever really did—well, that, and destroy repositories :-) ).

Comment: @DanielMann Could you share an answer for this? I am curios about that git command

Comment: @torek I'm using version 2.20.1.windows.1. I'm as confused as you I've used git a lot in the past however this pull request wiped it. I was able to save it thanks to the reflog (http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/02/09/reflog-your-safety-net.html). This tutorial really helped me out and I feel a lot safer now knowing this command exist.